# Wrong result from assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Can someone help me find what is wrong with the following program? I'm reading 'Programming from the Ground Up' and attempting to translate the examples into x86-64 assembly. The following program finds the largest number in a set of data. But when I assemble, link, and run it I get 0. Which is obviously not the largest number. It runs fine with 32-bit registers/instructions, but not 64-bit.

```
# PURPOSE: This program finds the largest value in a set of data.
#
#
# VARIABLES: %rax holds the current value. %rdi holds the largest 
#            value. %rbx holds the current index. data_items is the
#            actual set of data. The data is terminated with a 0.
#

.section .data

data_items:
    .long 76, 38, 10, 93, 156, 19, 73, 84, 109, 12, 21, 0

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movq $0, %rbx
    movq data_items(, %rbx, 4), %rax
    movq %rax, %rdi

loop_start:
    cmpq $0, %rax                     # Have we reached the end?
    je   loop_end
    incq %rbx                         # Increment the index.
    movq data_items(, %rbx, 4), %rax  # Load the next value.
    cmpq %rdi, %rax                   # Is new value larger?
    jle  loop_start
    movq %rax, %rdi                   # New val is larger, store
                                      # it.
    jmp  loop_start

loop_end:
    # The largest value is already in %rdi and will be returned as
    # exit status code.
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using movq which moves 64-bit values from your list that contains 32-bit values. That will give you wrong results. Define your list to hold 64-bit values instead: replace .long with .quad and replace 4 with 8 in the movs.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought that might be the problem, but I didn't know what the directive for 64-bit values was. Is there any advantage to using movq instead of movl with .long values in this situation?